# Populate the textbox value based on another textbox - Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba, auto-populate

I am trying to poulate a textbox to show a value based on another textbox. I am making a tabulation chart of students result and at the end of each calculation i want the firt record to show the 1st position and the second record to show 2nd and so on. I have performed all the calculation and sort the data to show in Descending format so that the highest marks show on top. Now i dont know how to populate the textbox to show 1st, 2nd and 3rd postions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form to a continuous form, and then modify the recordsource to use TOP 3 like:

```
Select Top 3 * From YourTable Order By [HighMark] Desc
```

Or create a new form as a continuous form or datasheetview form using this recordsource, and insert this form as a subform on a new main form.

Comment: i have added a textbox and in its control source i have typed  "=1" and changed to running sum. this solved the issue but can append the st, nd and rd with 1, 2 and 3 ? if yes then please let me know

Comment: _Running sum_ is on a report. It will show 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: i am using it on a report. everything is sorted out with your previous help and now its on final touches. can we add a % sign after every 1 2 3 ??

Comment: You could change the value to 0.01 and set the Format property of the textbox to _Percent_.